# Unexpected end of JSON input - Hyperledger Fabric while using putState()

Tags: node.js, json, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

```
async changeCarOwner(ctx, carNumber, newOwner) {

        const carAsBytes = await ctx.stub.getState(carNumber); 
        if (!carAsBytes || carAsBytes.length === 0) {
            throw new Error(`${carNumber} does not exist`);
        }
        const car = JSON.parse(carAsBytes.toString());
        car.owner = newOwner

        await ctx.stub.putState(carNumber, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(car)));

    }

}
```

**I keep getting an error: Unexpected end of JSON input. Why? I am trying to update an existing key-value pair in couchDb using the above code.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens at this line:

```
const car = JSON.parse(carAsBytes.toString());
```

It is due to the fact that `carAsBytes.toString()` does not evaluates to a properly formatted JSON string. The code you show seems fine, but the error is coming from elsewhere in your code.

Debugging tip: use the [debugger statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) to examine variables before the faulty line, simply add a `console.log(carAsBytes.toString())` before it.

Comment: That helped! Thank you.

Comment: @Roby it's the one I wrote. What are you missing?

Comment: @NinoFiliu struggle with retrival, in my chaincode function i use `const item = await ctx.stub.getState(key); return item;` But can parse back with JSON.parse